# How to set Electron Browser Window DevTools width?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, electron

How to set Electron Browser Window DevTools width?
I know how to set width and height of the mainwindow and open DevTools:

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1920, height: 1080} 
  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
```

But I would like to set DevTools dock width somehow, is it possible? Or set "Body" width so it leaves space for DevTools, setting width style does not help.

Comment: Please not that althought similar questions are answered elsewhere, they all deal with devTools in separate window. This question however specificaly asks for case where devTools are docked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this one by writing to the the `Preferences` file in the `userData` path on initialization

```js
const userDataPath = app.getPath("userData");
const prefPath = path.join(userDataPath, "Preferences");
const prefs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(prefPath, "utf-8"));
prefs.electron.devtools = {
  preferences: {
    "InspectorView.splitViewState": JSON.stringify({
      vertical: { size: 500 },
      horizontal: { size: 500 },
    }),
    uiTheme: '"dark"',
  },
};
fs.writeFileSync(prefPath, JSON.stringify(prefs));
```

Working example here: https://github.com/xdumaine/electron-quick-start

Comment: Wow this is quite the find!  Disappointing such a nasty hack is necessary.